# eclipse maven build java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I've got a very strange error related to Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)
Build id: 20201210-1552.

I have a project (jax-ws project) and I can build it with console, using maven 3.6.0 and java 1.8. war file is created without problem.

But when I tried to import project to eclipse, or clean project in eclipse I'm getting error below

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2021-03-08 12:07:50.992
!MESSAGE Error injecting: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.JarArchiver
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.JarArchiver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2021-03-08 12:07:51.001
!MESSAGE Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.JarArchiver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$ReflectiveProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2021-03-08 12:07:51.009
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.JarArchiver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$ReflectiveProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
...

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.m2e.core 4 75 2021-03-08 12:07:51.056
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'webservice'.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.JarArchiver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$ReflectiveProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
...
```

It looks like some problem related with codehaus.plexus plugins but if there was something wrong also I shouldn't be build a project in maven right?

I also set eclipse to use maven 3.6.0 and java1.8 but none of them work.
Tried to clean workspace, metadata and eclipse related project files and re-import project but no luck.

So where should I search the problem? (I have below dependencies in my m2 folder btw)

below you can find build config in pom.xml

```xml
<build>
        <finalName>vc-myservice</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>wsimport</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <packageName>com.myservice.verteilcenter.webservice</packageName>
                            <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>myservice.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            </wsdlFiles>
                            <wsdlLocation>../WEB-INF/wsdl/myservice.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                            <extension>true</extension>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc </source>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/jaxws/wsimport/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>${tomcat.path}</path>
                    <update>true</update>
                    <url>${tomcat.url}</url>
                    <server>${tomcat.server}</server>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warName>${project.build.finalname}</warName>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                                    <include>**/version</include>
                                    <!-- include any other file types you want to filter -->
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.12,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Comment: Hey, if you solved this, can you post an answer describing what you did?

Comment: @Torben unfortunately I couldn't find the root cause. Several times I uninstall eclipse and re-install and create a separate workspace folder. One of my tries the project started to work.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually solved it by updating maven-jar-plugin to 3.2.0. I just don't know what caused it to start failing all of a sudden...

Comment: I was also facing same problem just added plugin entry in pom.xml of project and its resolved.

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
</plugin>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the actual cause but it resolved by adding below plugin entry in pom.xml.

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    </plugin>
```